# Write CURL response in batch into a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, cmd

I'm trying to write my CURL response into a txt file and then back to a variable, but the variable remains empty.

```
@echo off
curl "http://www.example.com/check" >>temp.txt
set /p result=<temp.txt
echo %result%
pause
```

If I open the temp.txt in notepad I can see that it's all there.

I found out that the variable gets populated with text that I add from notepad, but skips all text that comes from the CURL request. 
Can it be wrong encoding? It's so strange that it would write the text in a way it can't read.

Comment: Use a `for /f` to directly process and parse the output of the curl command. And please give us a [mcve]

Comment: Why do you want to put the entire file in a variable?  What do you intend to do with the data once it is in `%result%`?

Comment: @abelenky I just need to check if the request returns success or not. The response is just a short message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch-variable can only have one line of text.
It doesn't really make sense for a variable to have the contents of an entire file.

And the last line of your `temp.txt` file is blank, so your `result` variable is getting just that blank line, and nothing else.

---

**Evidence:**

*Temp.txt file:*

```
Line 1
Hello World
Line 3
Last Line
```

*Run:*

```
set /p result=<temp.txt
echo %result%
```

*Result:*

```
Last Line
```

Comment: Did you actually test that code? Redirection of a file into the set /p command will only ever take the first line of the file in your example. Now if you redirected the contents of a file into a code block that had 4 set /p statements you could capture 4 lines into 4 separate variables.